# React Storybook Component Ajax Request How To

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I have a react application which is making ajax requests for data.

Since adding my components to [React Storybook](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook) my components do not render data.

Instead of providing default prop types, is it possible to render the actual data being used for my components?

Can I import Axios into storybook and make requests or something along these lines?

Answer (score 0):

Using [moxios](https://github.com/axios/moxios) you can set url capturing regexes to wait for certain requests, and pass back whatever mock data you want to the api calls.

For example:

```
// Route like /user/{id}/settings/{somesettingname}
moxios.stubRequest(/user\/[0-9a-zA-Z]+\/settings\/[^\/]/, {
    response: mockUserSettings,
    status: 200,
});
```